# Is it possible to display multiple images on 1 picturebox in running mode

Tags: vb6

When I try to google it for 3 days, I found that there is only 1 picture/image available in 1 picbox. My goal is to display multiple images, and they cannot overlap. If they overlap, there a red colour should be shown.

I'm using VB6. I'm using 1 `combobox1`, for select image n 1 commandbutoon. but when I select 2nd image in click button, the image on picbox will auto overwrite it. Is it caused by .cls ??

```
Private Sub Combo1_Click()
Dim pin As String
Dim intx As Integer
If UCase$(Combo1.List(intx)) = UCase$(pin) Then
Combo1.ListIndex = intx
End If
End Sub
Private Sub Command1_Click()

If Combo1.ListIndex = 0 Then
Set mPic = pin8.Image
ElseIf Combo1.ListIndex = 1 Then
Set mPic = pin12.Image

Else
Set mPic = pin16.Image
End If

    mPicWidth = Me.ScaleX(mPic.Width, vbHimetric, Picture1.ScaleMode)
    mPicHeight = Me.ScaleY(mPic.Height, vbHimetric, Picture1.ScaleMode)
    ShowPictureAtPosition mLeft, mTop

End Sub
```

Thank you.
Best regard,
chan

Comment: you mean the two pictures appears in the picture box at the same time ?

Comment: ya,after click commandbutton will add another..my task is make the 2 image wont overlap..drag within picbox. but cannot overlap 2 image.
Regard. any idea?? im very frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

Look, The only way to do that is to add 2 images as resources in the project then make one is the default picture or leave it blank as you wish.

The process now is when you click on the command button you switch between the two pictures.

Button Code:

```
if 

PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.<Name_of_res_file>.<Name_of_image1111_resource>

Then

PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.<Name_of_res_file>.<Name_of_image2222_resource>

Else

PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.<Name_of_res_file>.<Name_of_image1111_resource>

End If
```

This will switch between the 2 pictures. Hope this helps you.